# Is there a way to store data in mongoDB by reference?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

What I want to do is avoid data duplication (embedded), but also avoid fields relations by IDs.

Example:

`{ Books: [
        { id: 1, name: "Foo1", author: referenceToTheAuthorWithId1 },
        { id: 2, name: "Foo2", author: referenceToTheAuthorWithId1 }
]}`

`{ Authors: [
       {id: 1, name: "Bar"}
]}`

So each time I want to get a book, it will also retrieve its author, but that author object would be a reference to the Author collection.

Comment: It is not recommended to store app logic in your database. But try this. You can store a method that finds authors. Something like ```{ Books: [
        { id: 1, name: "Foo1", author: getAuthor(x) },
        { id: 2, name: "Foo2", author: getAuthor(x) }
]}``` the parameter is the id from authors array.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set `_id` fields for all of the documents you insert, and you can have identical ids in documents in various collections that refer to some common data.

In your example, if you replaced `Authors` with `Authorships` it would make *some* sense to have authorship id be the same as book id (at least this schema would support an author writing multiple books).

However, such  a schema does not support multiple authors per book.